# Как из VPN попасть в домен?

Tags: windows, dns, vpn, openvpn, windows-server-2012

У меня есть сервер (он же - домен-контроллер и днс сервер) Windows Server 2012 R2 x64. Настроен домен и лес. Я захотел получать доступ к ресурсам домена из дома. Я настроил OpenVPN и смог подключиться из дома к серверу. Но я не могу понять, как попасть в домен при подключении через VPN ?

Comment: Что значит "попасть в домен при подключении"? Это rdp на домен-контроллер и прозрачно заходить на шары?

Answer (score 1):

После подключения к VPN необходимо ввести машину в домен

(если не хотите вводить ее в домен, то придется думать только о необходимых ресурсах)